# Sublime text 3 git plugin PATH error - GIT Binary could not be found in PATH

Tags: git, sublimetext3

[image]

This is driving me crazy.. Have found the same issue elsewhere... but I cannot get this work on my windows 8.1.

Added C:\Git\bin to my Path environment variable.

Also tried updating the git_command var in the sublime Git plugin user settings... But still it appears!... any ideas would be very much appreciated... thanks

Here is my attempt to add my bin dir to the git_command property.

```
 {
// if present, use this command instead of plain "git"
// e.g. "/Users/kemayo/bin/git" or "C:\bin\git.exe"
"git_command": "C:/Git/git.exe"
 }
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: This thread can help http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9079

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just adding the incorrect path. It should be:

```
 {
// if present, use this command instead of plain "git"
// e.g. "/Users/kemayo/bin/git" or "C:\bin\git.exe"
"git_command": "C:/Git/bin/git.exe"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In "Preferences > Package Settings > Git Savvy > User"  add the following only ensure it is pointing to where ever your git.exe is.  Make sure you are using '/' and not '\' in your file path.

```
{
 "git_path": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe"
 }
```